# the sound was reversed but check50 it tell me that the file was not reversed as specified

Tags: c, wav

this code to reverse the sound of a wav clip and create a new wav file with the reversed audio in the C language
the sound was reversed but check50 it tell me that the file was not reversed as specified

What is wrong with this code؟:

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include "wav.h"
#include <string.h>

typedef uint8_t BYTE;

const int HEADER_SIZE = 44;

int check_format(WAVHEADER header);
int get_block_size(WAVHEADER header);

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    // Ensure proper usage
    // TODO #1
    if (argc != 3)
    {
        printf("usage: ./reverse input.wav output.wav\n");
        return 1;
    }

    // Open input file for reading
    // TODO #2
    FILE *input = fopen(argv[1], "rb");
    if (input == NULL)
    {
        printf("could not open file\n");
        return 2;
    }

    // Read header into an array
    // TODO #3
    WAVHEADER header;
    fread(&header, HEADER_SIZE, 1, input);

    // Use check_format to ensure WAV format
    // TODO #4

    if (check_format(header) == 5)
    {
        printf("Incorrect file format\n");
        return 3;
    }

    // Open output file for writing
    // TODO #5
    FILE *output = fopen(argv[2], "wb");
    if (output == NULL)
    {
        printf("could not open file\n");
        return 4;
    }

    // Write header to file
    // TODO #6
    fwrite(&header, HEADER_SIZE, 1, output);

    // Use get_block_size to calculate size of block
    // TODO #7
    int block_size = get_block_size(header);
    printf("block size is: %d\n", block_size);

    // Write reversed audio to file
    // TODO #8
    fseek(input, 0, SEEK_END);
    // long here = ftell(input);

    int *Buffer[block_size];
    do
    {
        fread(Buffer, block_size, 1, input);
        fwrite(Buffer, block_size, 1, output);
        fseek(input, -8, SEEK_CUR);
        long here = ftell(input);
        // printf("here is: %ld\n", here);
    }
    while (ftell(input) >= HEADER_SIZE);
    
    fclose(input);
    fclose(output);
}


int check_format(WAVHEADER header)
{
    // TODO #4
    BYTE *format = header.format;

    if (format[0] == 'W' && format[1] == 'A' && format[2] == 'V' && format[3] == 'E')
    {
        printf("is a wave file\n");
        return 0;
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Bad\n");
        return 5;
    }
}
[enter image description here][1]
int get_block_size(WAVHEADER header)
{
    // TODO #7
    int block_size = header.numChannels * (header.bitsPerSample / 8);
    return block_size;
}
```

I have already checked that it is an wav segment and print the header of the file, after that it is supposed to print each block from the input file to the output file starting from the end of the input file until reaching the header of the file (avoid printing the file header again), and I calculated the size of each block of the file .

We like to keep the order of channels for each audio block. For example, in a two-channel WAV file (stereophonic audio), we want to ensure that the first channel of the last input audio block becomes the first channel of the first output audio block.

Comment: Check the return values for `fread()` and `fwrite()`. For example, you seek to the end of the input file then try to read something.

Comment: Why is your buffer an array of `int *`?

Comment: Seeking backward eight bytes does not traverse the input stream backward unless `block_size` is four bytes. Your current code goes to the end, then tries to read `block_size` bytes, which should fail since it is at the end, then goes back 8 bytes, then tries to read `block_size` bytes, then goes back 8 bytes, and so on. You need to go to `block_size` bytes before the end, read `block_size` bytes, then go back 2 times `block_size` bytes, then read `block_size` bytes, then go back 2 times `block_size` bytes again, and so on. Get the code working on a plain text file first.